# Create a RecyclerView with multiple view from layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to have 2 layout in one RecyclerView

I have a recycler view list which is called Bookmark and it is parsed from an xml and this is all working , but I wanna in this recyclerview to put another layout which contains a button and that can be clickable.
Like in the photo the icons are from recyclerview and the plus button need to be compatible with the list, if the list is larger or smaller the button will be compatible with the space of list.

[image]

This is my new code for the Adapter which depends on the answer @LluisFelisart
And this is the error
`ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)`

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    public class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName,tvId,tvSearchUrl,tvNativeUrl;
        ImageView tvIcon;

        public ViewHolder0(@NonNull  View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
         /*   tvId=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSearchUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchUrl);
            tvNativeUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNativeUrl);*/
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView tvAddBookmark;

        public ViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvAddBookmark = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_button_add);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return position % 2 * 2;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);

        switch (i) {
            case 0: return new ViewHolder0(viewGroup);
            case 2: return new ViewHolder2(viewGroup);
        }

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0) holder;
                ((ViewHolder0) holder).tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
                ((ViewHolder0) holder).tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
                break;

            case 2:
                ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2) holder;

        }
        ((ViewHolder0) holder).tvIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(context, BookmarkActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ((ViewHolder0) holder).tvIcon.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityBookmarksFavorites.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        TextView tvName,tvId,tvSearchUrl,tvNativeUrl;
        ImageView tvIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull  View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
         /*   tvId=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSearchUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchUrl);
            tvNativeUrl=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNativeUrl);*/
        }



    }



}
```

This is the grid item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        style="@style/BookmarkIconIv" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
        style="@style/BookmarkTextTv" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout of button which I want to be in the recycler view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button_add"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Fragment which the recycler view it is shown

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    XmlPullParser pullParser;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    View paramView;
    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);

        myRecyclerView =  paramView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        try {
            XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"),"drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);
                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return paramView;
    }
    }
```

This is the layout bookmark which contains recyclerview

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use custom `itemViewType` and inflate it as an item inside RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you provide a code how to do this.
Or at least give me a help on my code.

Comment: @Spritzig can u add your code as sample project in Github??

Comment: I will try to make as sample project in Github

Comment: @Spritzig ok i'll check it can u explain what issue you are facing in above code and  what is your  expected output

Comment: I want the in the list of recycler view to have a button which it can be clicked and If the list it is larger the button will be compatible with the size of recyclerview. The problem whic I am facing is that the app crashes and the code above doesn‘t work in the list of recycler view to have another button the same as in photo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer

Follow this steps

#### First Create a two layout  for your Multiple viewType

**SAMPLE CODE**

> layout.layout_one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Name  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Icon  : " />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tvIcon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Id  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SearchUrl  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSearchUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="NativeUrl  : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNativeUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> layout.button_two

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Now you need to create two `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` for your both viewType

#### Now you need to Override [**`getItemViewType()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int))

- it Return the `viewType` of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.

#### Now in your **`onCreateViewHolder()`** method you need to return your instance of your **`ViewHolder`** based on your `viewType` which you will get using `getItemViewType()` method

#### Than in your **`onBindViewHolder()`** method based your `viewType` set your view property

> here is the sample code of **`RecyclerView.Adapter`** with multiple view types

## DataAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 0;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 1;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = null;
        // check here the viewType and return RecyclerView.ViewHolder based on view type
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_one, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_two, parent, false);
            return new ButtonViewHolder(view);
        }else {
            return  null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);
        // First check here the View Type
        // than set data based on View Type to your recyclerview item
        if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            viewHolder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl());
            viewHolder.tvNativeUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNativeUrl());
        } else if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;
            buttonViewHolder.imgButton.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // based on you list you will return the ViewType 
        if (arrayList.get(position).getViewType() == 0) {
            return ITEM_TYPE_ONE;
        } else {
            return ITEM_TYPE_TWO;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName, tvId, tvSearchUrl, tvNativeUrl;

        ImageView tvIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon);
            tvId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSearchUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSearchUrl);
            tvNativeUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNativeUrl);
        }
    }

    public class ButtonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        ImageView imgButton;

        public ButtonViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgButton);

        }
    }
}
```

## When you adding data in your list you need to provide the `viewtype` in list

Make some changes in your `Bookmark` POJO class

> `Bookmark` POJO class

```
public class Bookmark
{
    String name,id,nativeUrl,searchUrl;
    int icon;

    int viewType;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getNativeUrl() {
        return nativeUrl;
    }

    public void setNativeUrl(String nativeUrl) {
        this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
    }

    public String getSearchUrl() {
        return searchUrl;
    }

    public void setSearchUrl(String searchUrl) {
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
    }

    public int getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public void setViewType(int viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookmark{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", icon='" + icon + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nativeUrl='" + nativeUrl + '\'' +
                ", searchUrl='" + searchUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

> Sample activity code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mContext = this;

        myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        try {

            XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);

            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {

                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(0) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(1) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(5) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(2) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(3) + " * ");
                        Log.e("MY_VALUE", " * " + xpp.getAttributeValue(4) + " * ");


                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));

                        int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(1), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);

                        bookmark.setId(xpp.getAttributeValue(2));

                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(3));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(4));

                        // here you need to set view type
                        bookmark.setViewType(0);
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);
                    }
                }

                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // here i have added second viewType
        // you need to set as per your requirement
        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setViewType(1);
        bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.dishu);
        arrayList.add(bookmark);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

## **NOTE**

In the below code i have set second `viewType`  at the last index of `Arraylist`
 you need to set `viewType`  as per your requirement

For more information you can check below articles

- [Working with RecyclerView and multiple view types](https://medium.com/@paulnunezm/working-with-recyclerview-and-multiple-view-types-bb1e7dfc6993)
- [A RecyclerView with multiple item types](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050)
- [Android RecyclerView with Different Child Layouts](https://www.androidnovice.com/android-recyclerview-with-different-child-layouts/)
- [Android Pagination Tutorial—Handling Multiple View Types](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-recyclerview-multiple-view-types/)
- [Heterogenous Layouts inside RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)
- [Android RecyclerView Example – Multiple ViewTypes](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example)
- [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)
- [Android Multiple row layout using RecyclerView](http://www.coderconsole.com/2015/10/android-multiple-row-layout-using.html)

Comment: Something it is confusing me here the button view holder
`ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;`
It is coming the error
`Cannot cast ViewHolder to ButtonViewHolder`

Comment: @Spritzig kindly please check whole `DataAdapter` class i have made lots of change in that adapter class

Comment: can you help me in one another problem which I have, you know you have answered me with parsing the datas from an xml, do you know how to add now new data there, I have a layout which I can put string and save with shared preferences but I dont know how to show in the recyclerview list.

Comment: @Spritzig you can not add new data inside `res` folder at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can use different layouts  on the same RecyclerView , just override adapter  `getItemViewType`()  method and return a different int value for the button layout, in your example you should return for example 1 for the normal item and 2 for the button item.

The view type is passed as argument to `onCreateViewHolder()` method and depending of the viewType value you inflate the normal layout or the button layout.

It seems that you need also make `getItemCount()` to return one more than the array size

Hope it will help

Here an example:
[How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am little confused can you provide a code about your answer?

Comment: I have added the code but it is not working, I am changing the code to see what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Do this operations in your Activity.

```
        ArrayList<Bookmark>  data = new ArrayList<>();
        //data.addAll(your array list bookmark); uncomment this line add your all array list of bookmark
        Bookmark d = new Bookmark(0);
        data.add(d);
        mList.setAdapter(new BookMarkAdapter(activity, data));
```

Try This adapter

```
public class BookMarkAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Bookmark> data;

public BookMarkAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 1)
        return new ViewBookmarkHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_with_normal_image_and_textview, parent, false));
    else
        return new AddBookmarkHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_with_image, parent, false));

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Bookmark d = data.get(position);

     if (d.getType()==1) {
        ViewBookmarkHolder viewBookmarkHolder =(ViewBookmarkHolder) holder;
        // do your show image and textview operation here
    } else {

        AddBookmarkHolder addBookmarkHolder =(AddBookmarkHolder) holder;
        // do your on click operation here. Like adding new bookmark and update your arraylist and notify data changed for adapter.
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return data.get(position).getType();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
 }
}
```

Update this methods and variables in your Bookmark Pojo

```
public class Bookmark {

    private Integer type;

    public Bookmark(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Integer getType() {
        if(type==null)
            return 1;
        return type;
    }
  }
```