# How To Implement RecyclerView With Two Or More Different Card View With Data Fetch By Volley?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-cardview

How To Implement RecyclerView With Two Or More Different Card View With Data Fetch By Volley Like
1 : Discounted Products Have Separate View
and
2 : Non Discounted Product Have Separate View

Anyone Please Give Me Suggestion With Example I Want to Load Products From MySql Table

Like :

[image: See Image This Contain 2 Different Views]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779566/7666442

Comment: this can be the same card view layout you can just change what's shown as you're inflating it (visible/gone)

Comment: Please Provide any example I'm Creating  For the First Time I'm New .

Comment: there are tons of examples on how to create a recyclerview, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: But There is no example on How to (      you can just change what's shown as you're inflating it (visible/gone)        )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be the same card view layout you can just change what's shown as you're inflating it (visible/gone)